# firewalld settings for OpenVPN with https, ssh, and smtp

Tags: centos, firewall, vpn, openvpn, firewalld

I am configuring a remote CentOS 7 webapp server to wrap `https` and `ssh` inside OpenVPN, while keeping `smtp` running outside of OpenVPN.  I notice that, when I establish an OpenVPN connection from a Windows 7 Client using SecurePoint, I am only able to successfully connect to `https : / / 10.8.0.1`  and to `ssh username@10.8.0.1` when `https` and `ssh` are enabled BOTH in the public zone and in the private zone of firewalld.  This seems wrong because all the OpenVPN activity should be running through port 1192.  **So how should I configure `firewalld` so that `https` and `ssh` are only allowed inside the VPN, but so that `smtp` can still function outside the VPN?**

The output of `sudo firewall-cmd --list-all-zones` is as follows.  **What should I remove from the following configuration, and what should I add to it to accomplish the goals stated in paragraph 1 above?**  Are there zones below from whom everything should be removed?

```
block
  interfaces:
  sources:
  services:
  ports:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:

dmz
  interfaces:
  sources:
  services: ssh
  ports:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:

drop
  interfaces:
  sources:
  services:
  ports:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:

external
  interfaces:
  sources:
  services: ssh
  ports:
  masquerade: yes
  forward-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:

home
  interfaces:
  sources:
  services: dhcpv6-client ipp-client mdns samba-client ssh
  ports:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:

internal
  interfaces:
  sources:
  services: dhcpv6-client https ipp-client mdns samba-client ssh
  ports:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
        rule family="ipv4" source NOT address="10.8.1.1" service name="ssh" reject

public (default, active)
  interfaces: enp3s0
  sources:
  services: dhcpv6-client https openvpn ssh
  ports:
  masquerade: yes
  forward-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:

trusted
  interfaces:
  sources:
  services:
  ports:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:

work
  interfaces:
  sources:
  services: dhcpv6-client ipp-client ssh
  ports:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't added your `tun0` device to any zone, so it defaults to the `default` zone, which in your case is the `public` zone.

As root, run:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=internal --add-interface=tun0
```

You can then leave `ssh` and `https` enabled in the `internal` zone and disable it in the `public` zone.

Comment: I know hindsight is great, but may I suggest that you only test with `https` leaving `ssh` open on the `public` until everything works fully?  It sounds as if you've now configured the services/zones correctly, but are still suffering issues with `openvpn`.
Did you try connecting with a CentOS client?

Comment: `https : / / 10.8.0.1` seems to work now after the hosting company re-instated `ssh` in the public zone. I am reviewing the commands I typed, and they do not include a `reload` command. Do you think the problem may have been due to my not re-loading the firewall after adding the `tun` device? Also, `ssh` is working through the VPN now after I removed `https` from the public zone. I had to change `server.conf` to create a `route` for the administrator ip address so that the assigned ip address is no longer blocked by the `rich rule` in the firewall. Thank you and +1 for helping me find my way.

Comment: While we are still here for a moment, are you willing to please scan through the firewalld config in my OP and point out things that I can delete/remove, given my use case?  For example, `ssh` is enabled in the `dmz`, `external`, `home`, and `work` zones, in addition to the `internal` zone.  I have removed `ssh` and `https` from the `public` zone, but I am not sure what else I can safely remove.  I would like a minimalist installation.

Comment: @CodeMed - There is no need to remove any services from zones that aren't in use (that is, don't have an interface allocated to them).  Therefore you can leave `home`, `dmz` etc alone.  On the `public` zone you want to remove everything bar `smtp` (and possibly `ssh` for now). I'm assuming that the mail server is out-going only and you don't have a need for `pop3` or `imap`. On the `internal` zone, all you need is `ssh` and `https`.

Comment: @CodeMed - When you're 'experimenting' remotely with the firewall, do not use the `--permanent` option until you're certain your changes have worked. Without the option, settings are temporary and will not survive a reboot. If your service provider provides a web based interface to reboot, you can use that to reboot and return to your original config.  If they don't then run `shutdown -r +15` as root to reboot in 15 minutes. If your changes lock you out, you'll be able to log back in in 15 minutes. If they don't lock you out, run `shutdown -c` as root to cancel the reboot.